# Specifying float or double yet getting int value

Tags: c, function, floating-point, double, void

```
#include <stdio.h>

int diameter_fn(int r)
{
    return (2 * r);
}
void circumference_fn(int r)
{
    float pie = 22 / 7;
    float circum = (2 * pie * r);
    printf(", Circumference = %f", circum);
}
void area_fn(int r)
{
    float pie = 22 / 7;
    float area = (22 * r * r / 7);
    printf(" & the Area = %f", area);
}

int main()
{
    printf("\nName = Parth_Agrawal & UID = 22BCS10924\n");
    int radius;
    printf("Enter the Radius of Circle:\t\t");
    scanf("%d", &radius);
    printf("\nDiameter = %d", diameter_fn(radius));
    circumference_fn(radius);
    area_fn(radius);
    return 0;
}
```

I want to calculate Circumference, diameter and area of circle using functions yet I get non-perfect Circumference and area values.

I already tried replacing the float with double, `%f` with `%lf` etc but I am always getting the Circumference and area in xxx.0000 format,I.e, similar to Int converted to float format.
Like the area for 4 unit radius is 50.27 but it is giving me 50.000000 which is too much annoying.
This is the  Result I am getting
[image: Result I am getting] whereas this is the Result which I should get
[image: Result which I should get]

Comment: Hint: `22/7` is integer division.

Comment: I did 22.0 / 7 and 22.0 /7.0, I am getting Circumference correct but area still 50.000000 although the Circumference is within 0.015 range of original

Comment: If you want a value for π, `#include <math.h>` and use the `M_PI` macro if your standard library provides it, or `acosf(-1)` (`acos()` if you switch to doubles instead of floats like you probably should).

Comment: `float pie = 22 / 7;` --> `float pie = 22.0 / 7;` and `int r` (in arguments) --> `float r`. These ensure correct floating point math is used. And, you may want to change `%f` to `%g`

Comment: You're not using `pie` in the `area` function. Add the `.0` when defining `pie` and then use `pie * r * r`

Comment: (Style point: You should make your `area_fn()` and `circumference_fn()` functions act like `diameter_fn()` and return a value instead of printing it, and then print what they return.)

Comment: thank you, didn't knew that for calculating float every value within equation should be float

Comment: @Shawn I made all three as return types earlier but the results were the same so I was experimenting with them, then I lost and came here.

Comment: For π, you can use `static const double pi = 0x3.243f6a8885a308d313198a2e03707344ap0;`.

Answer (score 0):

> ... but it is giving me 50.000000 ...

OP is using integer math in many places where floating point math is needed.

```
void circumference_fn(int r) {
    float pie = 22 / 7;            // Integer math!!
    float circum = (2 * pie * r); 
    printf(", Circumference = %f", circum);
}

void area_fn(int r) {
    float pie = 22 / 7;           // Integer math!! pie not used
    float area = (22 * r * r / 7);// Integer math!!
    printf(" & the Area = %f", area);
}
```

Instead use FP math.
Scant reason to use `float`.  Use `double` as the default FP type.
Rather than approximate π with 22/7, use a more precise value.

```
#define PIE 3.1415926535897932384626433832795
void circumference_fn(int r) {
    double circum = (2 * PIE * r);
    printf(", Circumference = %f", circum);
}

void area_fn(int r) {
    double area = PIE * r * r;
    printf(" & the Area = %f", area);
}
```

---

**Other**

- All three functions should take a `double` argument and return a `double`.
- Use `"%g"` for printing.  It is more informative with wee values and less verbose with large ones.

Answer (score -1):

@Shawn is right: you are using integer math to calculate Pi. You should `#include <math.h>` and use `M_PI` instead of trying to calculate it yourself.

Comment: `M_PI` is not in the C standard and is not in all C implementations, so this will not work in some C implementations. Also, it is `#include`, not `#import`.

Comment: yeah it doesn't work in my Linux distro

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yeah, I'vee been writing too much Python recently. You're right. Fixed.